# Change record color based on property value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a oracle form that has two blocks . I would like to have the cell change color base on it's value null or not . How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two built-ins you can use: `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` and `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` (have a look at Forms Online Help System for more info).

- if you use the first one, it'll change all items in a tabular block (i.e. the whole column)
- it means that - if it really is a tabular form ("two blocks" sound like "master-detail" where detail usually *has* tabular layout - you should use the second one, `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` which will change only one instance of that item

For example, you'd do this:

```
if :system.cursor_item is null then
   set_item_instance_property(:system.cursor_item, current_record, visual_attribute, 'RED');
end if;
```

Comment: YEAH I DID IT THE SAME AND IT WORKS THANKS VERY MUCH